# Is there still any way I can download my developer story?

Tags: support, developer-story

It's been a while since I last used/needed the developer story, and today I wanted to update it to look for a new job but found out that it was already discontinued.

I liked the feature, but since it's gone, I was hoping I could at least access the data so I could rebuild it using a different method. I tried to find a way to reach StackOverflow support, but meta seemed like the only relevant place I could access to inquire about this.

Is anyone here able to help?

Comment: [this](https://stackapps.com/q/9361/78873) and [this](https://stackapps.com/q/9354/78873) community effort might be of interest to you (unfortunately, there is nothing on the part of SE that can help you - not sure if it is still possible to obtain the data).